# FFmpeg giving me failed to open segment error. Trying to parse .wav file into 30-second files

Tags: windows, command-line, ffmpeg

Here is the command I used and the output when I try and parse the .wav file into 30-second clips:

```
C:\Users\hmkur>ffmpeg -i C:\Users\hmkur\Desktop\Python\Transcribing_Audio\source\valve.wav -f segment -segment_time 30 -c copy parts/out%09d.wav
ffmpeg version git-2019-11-05-c54268c Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.2.1 (GCC) 20191010
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 35.101 / 56. 35.101
  libavcodec     58. 60.100 / 58. 60.100
  libavformat    58. 34.101 / 58. 34.101
  libavdevice    58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavfilter     7. 66.100 /  7. 66.100
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
[wav @ 0000023133098a00] Discarding ID3 tags because more suitable tags were found.
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, wav, from 'C:\Users\hmkur\Desktop\Python\Transcribing_Audio\source\valve.wav':
  Metadata:
    title           : valve
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100 (libsndfile-1.0.24)
  Duration: 00:06:47.20, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s
[segment @ 00000231334d18c0] Opening 'parts/out000000000.wav' for writing
[segment @ 00000231334d18c0] Failed to open segment 'parts/out000000000.wav'
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): No such file or directory
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
    Last message repeated 1 times
```

Comment: The segment muxer will not create folders, so `parts` has to be present beforehand.

Comment: @Gyan how could I get it to create the parts beforehand?

Comment: You have to do it with `md parts` in the parent directory.

Comment: @Gyan what is md parts? I'm still confused as to how I would get ffmpeg to create the audio files as needed through that command

Comment: Looks like you're unfamiliar with the CLI. See https://www.computerhope.com/issues/chusedos.htm

Comment: The `parts` folder doesn't appear to exist. You need to create it before running `ffmpeg`. So in Windows Explorer navigate to `C:\Users\hmkur\Desktop\Python\Transcribing_Audio\source` and create the `parts` folder, or use the `md` command in `cmd` as mentioned by Gyan. Then run `ffmpeg`.